# Postman: JSON test for count giving error

Tags: json, postman

I need to count the number of objects in `fdArea` array.

Used code below but it is giving an error:

> There was an error in evaluating the test script:  JSONError: Unexpected token 'o' at 1:2 [object Object]

Expected Result: **count = 14**

I am not quite able to understand the error.

Plz, help me with the correct code to test.

---

Response to parse:

```
"fdArea":
[{
        "dAreaId": 2,
        "dArea": "Belgium",
        "dPrefixCode": "BE"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 3,
        "dArea": " Czech",
        "dPrefixCode": "CZ"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 6,
        "dArea": "France",
        "dPrefixCode": "FR"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 4,
        "dArea": " Germany",
        "dPrefixCode": "DE"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 7,
        "dArea": " Hungary",
        "dPrefixCode": "HU"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 8,
        "dArea": "Italy",
        "dPrefixCode": "IT"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 9,
        "dArea": "Netherlands",
        "dPrefixCode": "NL"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 10,
        "dArea": " Poland",
        "dPrefixCode": "PL"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 12,
        "dArea": "Slovakia",
        "dPrefixCode": "SK"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 14,
        "dArea": "South Africa",
        "dPrefixCode": "ZAF"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 5,
        "dArea": "Spain",
        "dPrefixCode": "ES"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 11,
        "dArea": "Sweden",
        "dPrefixCode": "SE"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 1,
        "dArea": " United Arab Emirates",
        "dPrefixCode": "ARE"
    },
    {
        "dAreaId": 13,
        "dArea": "United Kingdom",
        "dPrefixCode": "UK"
    }]
```

Code:

```
var responseJson = JSON.parse();
var count = responseJson.value.length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check how many objects are in the `fdArea` array you could use the Lodash `_.each()` function in the `Tests` tab, to log out the number to the console:

```
_.each(pm.response.json(), (arrItem) => {
        console.log(arrItem.fdArea.length)
})
```

With a `response` data set like this one:

```
[
   {
      "fdArea":[
         {
            "dAreaId":2,
            "dArea":"Belgium",
            "dPrefixCode":"BE"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":3,
            "dArea":" Czech",
            "dPrefixCode":"CZ"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":6,
            "dArea":"France",
            "dPrefixCode":"FR"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":4,
            "dArea":" Germany",
            "dPrefixCode":"DE"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":7,
            "dArea":" Hungary",
            "dPrefixCode":"HU"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":8,
            "dArea":"Italy",
            "dPrefixCode":"IT"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":9,
            "dArea":"Netherlands",
            "dPrefixCode":"NL"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":10,
            "dArea":" Poland",
            "dPrefixCode":"PL"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":12,
            "dArea":"Slovakia",
            "dPrefixCode":"SK"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":14,
            "dArea":"South Africa",
            "dPrefixCode":"ZAF"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":5,
            "dArea":"Spain",
            "dPrefixCode":"ES"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":11,
            "dArea":"Sweden",
            "dPrefixCode":"SE"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":1,
            "dArea":" United Arab Emirates",
            "dPrefixCode":"ARE"
         },
         {
            "dAreaId":13,
            "dArea":"United Kingdom",
            "dPrefixCode":"UK"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

It would return the number `14` in the Postman Console.